# Uniqueness of Laplace equation by energy method.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Is there any energy method to show the uniqueness of the Laplace equation(2D)?

I can show easily the uniqueness of the Laplace equation with the Dirichlet conditions by using Green's identity. But I want to know that, Do we have any energy method? (Like we have an energy method to prove the uniqueness of heat and wave equations.) If it is then please specify!

Comment: Using Green’s identity is usually to be an “energy method”, so I’m not entirely certain what you’re looking for

Comment: Can you explain how?